# Ruby: Ubuntu Gedit Problem possible with Spaces

Tags: ruby, syntax, ubuntu, gedit

can someone tell me why this works in my gedit on ubuntu

```
def initialize (product_id,category_id,category_name)
```

but this does not. It thows a syntax error and says that I am missing a ")"

```
def initialize (product_id, category_id, category_name)
```

I spent about 2 hours running through all the rest of my code and this is what fixed the syntax error.  I had to change it where I call the method and in its definition.  The rest of my code is 100% the same.. Is gedit doing something with my spaces?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to have a space between the method name and the arguments list for that method. It should be:

```
def initialize(product_id, category_id, category_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

While agreeing with @Ryan that you shouldn't have a space between initialize and the bracket, both versions worked fine in IRB for me:

```
class Foo
  def initialize (product_id,category_id,category_name)
  end
end

class Bar
  def initialize (product_id, category_id, category_name)
  end
end

Foo.new(1, 2, 3)
Bar.new(1, 2, 3)
```

Given these versions of irb on karmic koala:

```
agrimm@csb1:~$ irb --version
irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)
agrimm@csb1:~$ irb1.9.1 --version
irb 0.9.5(05/04/13)
```

So if gedit is refusing to accept the code, it's being a bit lazy.

As a side note, you should provide the error's stack trace (so long as it doesn't have top secret information), and ideally provide code like I have above so someone can cut and paste it into their computer. Make it easier for us!

Comment: @Downvoter: Why the downvote? Is what I said incorrect, or are you objecting to the last paragraph? (BTW, I know it's not the OP who downvoted me)